# understanding Green function, Boundary element method, Green element method from scratch

Tags: numerical-methods, greens-function, greens-theorem, parabolic-pde

I am newly exposed to  Green function, Boundary element method, Green element method  and would like to understand them from scratch in solving Parabolic PDES (specifically flow In heterogeneous porous media)

I have went through a lot of papers and book yet all was pretty advanced for me to cope.

can you please guide me to lecture notes, videos, basic books easy to comprehend

appreciate your inputs.
regards

Comment: I am not deep into BEM and GEM, but usually parabolic PDEs (e.g. $∂_tu-Δu=f$, are solved combining ODE-methods ($∂_t$), e.g. Euler method, with elliptic PDE-methods ($-Δu$), e.g. FEM. BEM/GEM would be the method used for the elliptic PDE part. Therefore, I would start with some basic lecture notes about numerics for ODEs, and then some lecture notes about elliptic PDEs.  [I personally prefer lecture notes compared to books]

Comment: About flow in porous media:  [Olaf Ippisch](https://www.mathematik.tu-clausthal.de/en/personen/olaf-ippisch/) gave a lecture titled "Numerical Simulation of Transport Processes in Porous Media", that I attended few years ago in Heidelberg. He has written lectures notes in English. It might be a bit advanced though, but I really liked that lecture.

Answer (score 1):

There is two principal "dummy books" you must read to understand Boundary element method(BEM).

1. Boundary Element Method with  Programming for Engineers and Scientists.
   Dr. Gernot Beer.
2. Boundary elements theory and applications.
   Dr. J.T. Katsikadelis

the firs one is pretty useful when you going to star programming the method.The second one helped you to understand Green function, I have to admit that there are something quiet don't know about the mathematical background, but still the knowledge you get reading is enough to star programming.

People often recommend Boundary Elements (DR. Carlos Brebbia) but this one is quit difficult to understand for me.

postscript: a don't speak very well english, so sorry for my gramar grammar.

postscript:postscript: BEM community is getting older, so is very difficult you run into some pro-BEM programmers in stackexchange, you must send an email to some of paper's and books authors to get some information

postscript:postscript:postscript: I'm not pro-BEM programmer.